# 2 listsItems rellenar uno a partir del otro JSF

Tags: jsf, java-ee

Buenas tardes,

tengo 2 listItems el primero esta rellenado con los valores Persona fisica y Persona Juridica y el segundo esta rellanado con los valores DNI, PASAPORTE yo quiero a la hora de elegir Persona fisica en el primero me devuelve el segundo con solamante el valor DNI y desactivado, el codigo que hice es el siguiente :

codigo controlador:

```
public List<SelectItem> getComboTipoIdentificador() {
        List<SelectItem> li = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        if (cliente.getFiguraJuridica().equals(Codificadoras.ATC_FIG_JURIDICA_F)){
            li= this.cargaComboCodificadora(Constantes.TABLA_TIPO_IDEN, true);
        }else{
            li.add(new SelectItem(new Integer(1),"DNI_NIF"));
        }
        return li;
    }
```

codigo xhtml:

```
<n:campo clase="scCampoLista scOcupa1de6" label="#{textAtc['atc.altaCliente.labelFiguraJuridica']}*">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="figuraJuridica" value="#{altaSimplificadaForm.cliente.figuraJuridica}" >
         <f:selectItems value="#{altaSimplificadaForm.comboFiguraJuridica}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</n:campo>
<n:campo clase="scCampoLista scOcupa1de6" label="#{textAtc['atc.altaCliente.lableTipoIdentificacion']}*">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="tipoIdentificacion" value="#{altaSimplificadaForm.cliente.tipoIdentificador}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{altaSimplificadaForm.comboTipoIdentificador}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</n:campo>
```

me da el error siguiente : value="#{altaSimplificadaForm.comboTipoIdentificador}": Error reading 'comboTipoIdentificador'
algo esta malo en la función  getComboTipoIdentificador?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No es recomendable construir tu lista de SelectItems en el getter de comboTipoIdentificador, la razón es que JSF invoca los getters mas de una vez durante el ciclo de vida del bean (Podés leer mas sobre esto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Seria mejor preguntar si la lista ya esta cargada antes de construirla nuevamente y asi ahorrarnos algunos problemas que puedan ocurrir:

```
public List<SelectItem> getItems() {
  if ( this.items == null ) {
     this.items = buildItems();
  }
  return this.items;
}

private List<SelectItem> buildItems() {
     // Logica para construir los items
}
```

Sobre tu problema en si, algunas ideas:

1. Estas asignando `altaSimplificadaForm.comboTipoIdentificador`al `<f:selectItems>` por lo que imagino que tienes una variable comboTipoIdentificador en el bean altaSimplificadaForm; sin embargo, en el metodo `getComboTipoIdentificador()` no asignas los items a esa variable sino a otro arrayList `li`. Esto en teoría no deberia dar problemas pero de todas maneras no tiene mucho sentido.
2. El metodo `cargaComboCodificadora` maneja excepciones? Quiza se este produciendo alguna excepcion y JSF no es capaz de detallarla.